# Binary search for insert char string. Where is the bug?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

I have array of strings. I must find one char string in array of strings by binary search algoritm. If there is this one string then function must return position and return true otherwise this function must return position for insert string in array and false.
I have somewhere bug, but I dont know where ((

Example:

```
bool Binary_search ( char * arr_strings[], int & position, const char * search_string )
{
    int start = 0 ;
    int end = 10 - 1; // arr_strings [10]
    int for_compare;
    int middle;

    while ( start <= end )
    {
        middle = ( start + end ) / 2;
        for_compare = strcmp ( arr_strings[middle], search_string  );

        if ( for_compare > 0 )
        {
            start = middle + 1;
        } 
        else if ( for_compare < 0 )
        {
            end = middle - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // if search_string is found in array, then function return position in array of strings and return true
            position = middle;
            return true;
        }
    }
    // if search_string is not found in array, then function must return position for insert string and return false 
    position = middle;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think `char * arr_strings[]` should be `char  arr_strings[]` to start with, but it depends on how you call Binary_search too.

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: @stardust_ Nope, it shouldn't.

Comment: if there isnt search_string in arr_strings[] then function return bad position for insert this string into arr_strings[]

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Ah I see spoke too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your insertion position is not right.

You should do something like the following:

```
bool Binary_search ( char * arr_strings[], const char * search_string )
{           //^^^you are not doing recursive, so you don't need position as parameter 
    int start = 0 ;
    int end = 10 - 1; // arr_strings [10]
    int for_compare;
    int middle;
    int position = -1; 

    while ( start <= end )
    {
        middle = ( start + end ) / 2;
        for_compare = strcmp ( arr_strings[middle], search_string  );

        if ( for_compare > 0 )
        {   //^^^here should switch the order
            end = middle - 1;
        } 
        else if ( for_compare < 0 )
        {
            start = middle + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            position = middle;
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (position == -1)
    {
        if(strcmp(arr_strings[middle],search_string) <0 )
        {
            position = middle + 1;
        }else 
        {
            position = middle;
         }
    }

    return position;
}
```

Comment: Good, but Im afraid that algoritm will be slowly. I think on the end must be some two IF or other for position

Comment: @user1779502 I just updated the post, now it should work as you expected. I tested with 3 strings only, it worked fine (sure change end to 2)

Comment: thank you for your work, but I still have some error with sorting with this code. Maybe error is somewhere other place. I must use this function for inserting string. If in array isnt string then fuction must return false and Im using position for insert otherwise function return true and return by reference position in array fot next work

Comment: @user1779502 if you want to return both "found or not" and insertion position or index, you'd better not use `bool` as return type. return pair instead, one indicates whether found or not, the other indicates either insert position or index based on found or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe it should be:

```
if ( for_compare > 0 )
{
    end = middle - 1;
} 
else if ( for_compare < 0 )
{
    start = middle + 1;
}
```